# vmware backup procedure

Tags: virtual-machine, esxi

I am attempting to migrate a VM located on a ESXi 4.1 host to a ESXi 5.0 host changing the datastore completely. I have researched through VMware site and I see a few methods which are exporting the ova, using the update manager, even a 3rd party tool called VEEAM.  I tried to use VEEAM but it failed due to version restrictions. Yes I am using a free version of VM on the 4.1 server.  I am currently testing the OVA method as we speak, but I figured I would ask what is the quickest and secure method to do the transfer?

Answer (score 0):

connect both ESXes to same vCenter , there you can use migrate option to migrate host and datastore